# How can I obtain seperate spin-up and spin-down bands while considering Spin Orbit Coupling in Quantum ESPRESSO?

Tags: quantum-espresso, band-structure, magnetism, spin-orbit-coupling, spin-polarization

I have been studying a magnetic material with SoC taken into consideration. The main aim was to obtain the band structure.

when I use `spin_component = 1` in the **bands.x** input file, I get a bands.dat file containing the bands for the spinup configuration.

But on using `spin_component = 2`, it throws the following error.

```
 %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
     Error in routine punch_bands (1):
     incorrect spin_component
 %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
```

I found this discussion on the [pw-Forum](https://www.quantum-espresso.org/Doc/INPUT_BANDS.html#idm22), in which it was stated that:

> In the spin-orbit case starting with zero starting_magnetization on
> all atoms imposes time reversal symmetry. The magnetization is never
> calculated and kept zero (the internal variable domag is .FALSE.).

**So is there a way to obtain the spin-polarized bandstructure in Quantum ESPRESSO whilst taking into consideration Spin-Orbit Coupling?**

Comment: 'Spin-polarization' and SOC don't go along with each other. The wave function becomes a spinor when you include spin-orbit coupling. So there's no meaning of 'majority' or 'minority' carrier, since the spins can point in different directions.

Answer (score 2):

- If you are considering SOC, which means the noncolinear calculations are performed. I assume that the eigenstate of the Kohn-Sham equation is labeled by $|atom, k, orbital, spin \rangle$. To obtain a spin-polarized band structure, you should do a fat band analysis with the consideration of the different spin components:

  - $\langle atom, k, orbital, spin|s_x \rangle$ (plus=left;minusright)
  - $\langle atom, k, orbital, spin|s_y \rangle$ (plus=front;minus=back)
  - $\langle atom, k, orbital, spin|s_z \rangle$ (plus=up;minus=down)
- You may take a look at my answer for this post: [Properties that can be deduced from Band structure and DOS](https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/questions/1791/properties-that-can-be-deduced-from-band-structure-and-dos/2396#2396)
- For your question, the key problem is to output band structure with projection to spin. The same function is realized with [LORBIT=11](https://www.vasp.at/wiki/wiki/index.php/LORBIT) in VASP.